# How to calculate multiple inputs separated by space in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def checkGrade(raw):
    ''' (int) -> object (i.e., int OR str)
     Assign grade from raw score
    >>> checkGrade(74)
    3
    >>> checkGrade(82)
    4
    >>> checkGrade(-5)
    'Error, raw score exceed min score'
    >>> checkGrade(210)
    'Error, raw score exceed max score'
    '''
    if raw>100:
        score = "Error, raw score exceed max score" 
    elif raw>80:
        score = 4.00
    elif raw>70:
        score = 3.00
    elif raw>60:
        score = 2.00
    elif raw>50:
        score = 1.00
    elif raw>0:
        score = 0
    else:
        score = "Error, raw score exceed min score" 
    return score
```

Now I want to do something like this (shown in docstring):

```
def calGPA(n):
    ''' (str) -> float
    Take all the raw scores, limited to 10 subjects, and 
    calculate GPA. Raw scores must be in range of 0 - 100.
    >>> calGPA("77 45 77 55 87")
    2.2
    >>> calGPA("66 67 45 89")
    2.0
    >>> calGPA("87 91 84 89") 
    4.0
    >>> calGPA("87 91 84 103")
    'Error'
    >>> calGPA("77 45 77 55 87 21 35 65 98 12 23 45") 
    'Error'
    '''
```

The raw marks input is in a string separated by spaces. How can I calculate the GPA using `checkGrade()` function from such an input? I tried this:

```
map(int, s.split())
```

but it doesn't work.

---

**Edited to add new requirement**

And if I want to change all input into letters like `calGPA("A B C D F")` instead of `calGPA("80 70 63 55 40")`, and if input contains anything apart from "A", "B", "C", "D", "F" such as `calGPA("A C B Z S")` then the output should be "Error". What should I do in order to get "Error" if an element is not one of "A", "B", "C", "D", "F"?

Comment: Please format your code and give a better explanation of the error than "it does not work".

Comment: Use `raws` as the argument name instead of `raw`.  Then, create a `for` loop: `for raw in map(int, raws.split()):`.  Indent the rest of the code so that it is in the `for` loop.

Comment: I don't think using `raw` as a variable name is a problem in this case.

Comment: @ zondo Thank you, I'm  a newbie here.

Comment: First, editing the question in such a way that it makes the current accepted answer invalid is not allowed. Yet I am editing my answer.

Comment: **Take a look at this meta post about ["chameleon questions"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the string containing the raw marks, and then use your `checkGrade` function to get the score for that raw mark. Try this:

```
def checkGrade(raw):
    if raw>100:
        score = "Error, raw score exceed max score" 
    elif raw>80:
        score = 4.00
    elif raw>70:
        score = 3.00
    elif raw>60:
        score = 2.00
    elif raw>50:
        score = 1.00
    elif raw>0:
        score = 0
    else:
        score = "Error, raw score exceed min score" 
    return score

def calGPA(s):
    raw_marks = s.split()
    num_subjects = len(raw_marks)
    if num_subjects > 10:
         print('Limit for number of subjects exceeded')
         return
    total = 0
    for raw in raw_marks:
        total += checkGrade(int(raw))
    print('GPA: {}'.format(total/num_subjects))

calGPA("77 45 77 55 87")
```

Outputs:

```
GPA 2.2
```

---

**Edit to reflect your new requirement**

```
def calGPA(s):
    gpas = s.split()
    valid_grades = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F']
    if not all(gpa in valid_grades for gpa in gpas):
        print("Error")
```

**P.S.: Editing the question in such a way that it makes the currently accepted answer invalid is *not allowed* and *highly discouraged.***

Comment: If I want to change all input into letters like calGPA("A B C D F") instead of calGPA("80 70 63 55 40").And apart of "A", "B", "C", "D", "F" such as calGPA("A C B Z S") then the output should be "Error". What should I do?

Comment: thank you anyway, and sorry about editing the question i will remember.

Comment: It's okay, you have now learned this rule about editing question. :) You may want to add that last comment of yours as a comment to the question, and delete from here.

Answer (score 1):

Simply cast all the items in the string to integers then apply the function to each casted number like so

```
checkGPA = lambda data: map(checkGrade, map(int, data.split())) # apply the function to int
```

Answer (score 0):

`CalGPA(int(x) for x in s.split())` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
def calGPA(n):
    iter = map(int, n.split())
    return sum(checkGrade(x) for x in iter)/len(iter) if len(iter)<10 and all(el <100 for el in iter) else 'Erreur'
```

`all(el <100 for el in iter` will check if all elements in `iter` are in range `0-100`.It will return `False` if one element is out of range.

Comment: If I want to change all input into letters like calGPA("A B C D F") instead of calGPA("80 70 63 55 40").And apart of "A", "B", "C", "D", "F" such as calGPA("A C B Z S") then the output should be "Error". What should I do with  all(el <100 for el in iter  in order to get "Error" if one element is not "A", "B", "C", "D", "F"

Comment: @MrMaster_P Define  `EXCLUDE = ("A", "B", "C", "D", "F" )` then use `all(el not in EXCLUDE for el in iter)`